# Analysing subsets of data from one data frame defined by another data frame

Tags: r

I need to know how to take the mean/median etc. from rows of one data frame selected according to whether they meet a condition that refers to another. Difficult to explain, so I'll just give an example.

```
> d
   Position Value
1         0  0.20
2         5  0.30
3        10  0.45
4        15  0.23
5        20  0.71
6        25  0.10
7        30  0.20
8        35  0.22
9        40  0.80
10       45  0.50
11       50  0.31
12       55  0.40
```

And also:

```
  Segment Start End
1       1     0  15
2       2    20  40
3       3    45  55
```

Basically, "d" gives a variable's value at a certain 'position.' "d2" gives start and end points (or positions) of several 'segments' of the data from "d". Now, what I want is the mean and median of the "value" entries from "d" in each "segment." So for segment 1, because it has start and end positions 0 and 15, respectively, it would return the mean of the entries for 0, 10, and 15 from "d". Note that the segments are not necessarily of equal length, so it would not work to just take the mean of the first n entries, second n entries, third n entries, and so on.

One could think of the segments as segments on a chromosome; and each point on the chromosome has a "value" that describes some characteristic of that point on the chromosome, and I have data on what this value equals at each point, and also data on where each segment begins and ends (segments are all contiguous, just not equal length), and now want to compute, say, the mean value for all the points within each segment. Suffice it to say, unlike with my example, in the actual data set there are far too many segments to compute these manually, hence the question. Thanks.

Comment: Who is this...??? You could explain better..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
mapply(function(s,e) {
    mean(d$Value[d$Position>=s & d$Position<=e])}
, d2$Start, d2$End)
```

That should give you a vector the same length as the number of rows of d2 so you where where all the values belong.